# How can I check my config files my.cnf for example

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux, debian

I have 2 config files, **master.cnf** and **slave.cnf**, each containing a group **[mysdql0]** or **[mysqld1]** respectively.

I have an almost identical setup across different servers and all but one work correctly with a single **my.cnf** file which has the following lines;

```
!include /etc/mysql/master.cnf
!include /etc/mysal/slave.cnf
```

and when I run **mysqld_multi report** I get the output I expect, relating to mysqld0 & mysqld1

However, there is one box that simply returns no instance groups and in an attempt to diagnose this issue, I moved the configuration for **master.cnf** into **my.cnf** and to my surprise I am then able to run **mysqld_multi report** and also start and stop that instance without issue.

For whatever reason, when I split this out into the two files as mentioned above and a single my.cnf file, it just doesnt see any instance groups.

My question is twofold reallyl

**1)** What could be causing this? given the same configuration is up and running on a few other servers.

**2)** Secondly, how can I diagnose this issue? (is there a way to see if the **my.cnf** file is being parsed and more importantly getting to the **!include** lines etc?

I've tried running **mysqld --validate-config** on newer versions but this just gives an error **unknown option --validate-config**

I'm running on a mixture of Debian boxes and version range including;

5.5.55-0+deb8u1 and 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1

**UPDATE 21-JAN-2021**
I've updated my post based on comments received and focusing on the prolbem box only. the above can be treated as merely background information.

Ok, so I have amended things slightly in an attempt to put across what the current problem is.

So currently, I have a file **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** which is as follows;

```
[client-server]

!include /etc/mysql/my_master.cnf
!include /etc/mysql/my_slave.cnf
```

I also have two other **cnf** files, surprisingly **my_master.cnf** and also **my_slave.cnf** and these contain sections as below;

**my_master.cnf** contains **[mysqld0]**
**my_slave.cnf** contains **[mysqld1]**

both of the above have configurations that work.

If I run **mysqld_multi report** I get;

```
Reporting MySQL servers
No groups to be reported (check your GNRs)
```

If I run **my_print_defaults --config-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf mysqld0**

I get the output I'm expecting for **[mysqld0]**

and similarly, if I run **my_print_defaults --config-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf mysqld1**

I get the output I'm expecting for **[mysqld1]**

but still can neither report, nor start either of my instances with **mysqld_multi**

If I simply rename **my_master.cnf** or **my_slave.cnf** to **my.cnf** then **mysqld_report** reports as expected and I can also start and stop that instance as expected.

Comment: does `my_print_defaults --defaults-group-suffix 0 --mysqld` help in printing out what is read?

Comment: @danblack I get no output from your exact suggestion but if I run `my_print_defaults --config-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --mysqld0` (or mysqld1) I get as I would expect on my other boxes but this particular box gives no output.  However, if I rename my my_master.cnf to my.cnf then the former `my_print_defaults --config-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --mysqld0` gives the output as expected. I'm completely stumped as it happens...

Comment: I think this must be down to either the version of **mysqld_multi** or the version of mysql running. Noted on a few other forums, comments about mysqld_multi not being able to parse **!include** and so on.